# Fluid Mechanics Proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus

- In a classical fluid every molecule  making up the fluid is subject to Newton's laws.
- In a continuum approximation of a large number of these particles we may think in terms of a small element of the continuum, containing those particles, being subject to Newton's laws.
- Thinking in terms of local conditions, the fluid elements follow a path with a tangent to the path given by the fluid velocity vector field,

**v**(x,y,z,t)=d**r**/dt=dx/dt**i**+dy/dt**j**+dz/dt**k**

If this were air, we would think of this as wind velocity.

We need the acceleration to employ Newton's  second law,
**a**(x,y,z,t)=d**v**/dt,

Based on what is written above, I really was having difficulty proving if the below statement C. is true or false, I am also attaching my rough work of what I've done but would really appreciate some feedback.

[Statement C.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhiN5.png)
[Rough Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKFtb.jpg)

Comment: welcome, and there https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/161705 to help you write the equations :v

Comment: It looks like you know how to do bold face. Use \nabla for the gradient, \frac{dv}{dt} for the ordinary derivative and \partial within the \frac to get partial derivatives. These are all covered in the link provided by cand.

Comment: See [Navier–Stokes Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier–Stokes_equations).

Comment: Take a look at [this recursive answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3144712/mechanics-of-fluids-proof).